# Valid method to obtain a basis of a topological subspace?

Tags: general-topology, definition, examples-counterexamples

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $Y \subset X.$ We know that if $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $\tau$ and $\tau_{\small{Y}}$ is the subspace topology on $Y$, then we can obtain a basis for $\tau_{\small{Y}}$
by taking the collection $\mathcal{B}_Y$ of intersections $Y \bigcap B$ as $B$ ranges over all the sets in $\mathcal{B}$.

I was wondering if as another genereal method to obtain a basis for $\tau_{\small{Y}}$ by taking the collection $\mathcal{S}_Y$ of all the sets $B$ in $\mathcal{B}$ such that $B \subset Y$? If yes, will we always have that $\mathcal{B}_Y=\mathcal{S}_Y$?

As an example I took the interval $[1,2]$ with the induced Euclidean topology and it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

No. Take a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Also, your case $[1,2]$ doesn't seem to work for me. It seems neither $1$ nor $2$ would have a neighbourhood.

Comment: The basis elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are 2-dimensional whereas a line is 1-dimensional. So it is a counterexample because there is no element of the basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is included in a line, right?

Comment: @derthomas Yes, there is no element of the basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in a line, but the justification you used is a bit too naive. In truth, my example could be changed for any $A$ in any topological space which has empty interior. This is the crux of the example: you won't find open sets in there (only the empty set).

Comment: Ok, I see. But in the case of $[1,2]$ with the induced Euclidean topology it is another method to construct a basis?

Comment: I don't think so, see my edit. It seems there is no neighbourhood of $1$ or $2$ in what you propose.

Comment: You mean that for example $]1,a[$ with $a \leq 2$ could not be formed with elements of $\mathcal{S}_Y$?

Comment: No. That is not a neighbourhood of $1$. I mean, for example, $[1,\frac{3}{2})$, or in fact any induced open set that contains $1$.

Comment: Yes, but $[1,\frac{3}{2})$ is not open set for the Euclidean topology, so why would you require that $1$ and $2$ have a neighbourhood?

Comment: $[1,\frac{3}{2})$ *is* an open set on the induced topology on $[1,2]$. It is not open on $\mathbb{R}$, but it is open on $[1,2]$.

Comment: Okay, now I do see clearly.The belief that $[1,\frac{3}{2})$ is not open on the induced topology on $[1,2]$ actually led me to this fallacious method. Thank you.